# In Python re.sub function, how can I reference group 0 using \n syntax?

Tags: python, regex, replace, str-replace

In Python `re.sub()`'s replacement parameter, I want to refer to the whole matched string, the group 0. However, it doesn't work as expected.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d)\1", r"\0\1", "aa11bb22cc33")
'aa\x001bb\x002cc\x003'
```

Note that the `\1` does correctly refer to group 1. I have to use `\g<n>` syntax to refer to group 0.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d)\1", r"\g<0>\1", "aa11bb22cc33")
'aa111bb222cc333'
```

I want to know, is it possible to use `\n` syntax to refer group 0 in the replacement parameter?

Comment: From the docs: \number Matches the contents of the group of the same number. **Groups are numbered starting from 1.**

Comment: @wwii Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that before. This is different to many other regex engines.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, strictly speaking, but: if the goal is to replace consecutive digit pairs with consecutive digit triplets, couldn't you do it without referencing group zero at all? Something like `re.sub(r"(\d)\1", r"\1\1\1", "aa11bb22cc33")`

Comment: @Kevin This is not a real problem and I just use it to demonstrate my question.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Good thing I didn't write my suggestion as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. You could however put a capture group around the entire expression and reference that with `\1` and the inner group with `\2`.

```
>>> re.sub(r"((\d)\2)", r"\1\2", "aa11bb22cc33")
>>> 'aa111bb222cc333'
```